# Overload Function Error Messages

Tags: c++, overloading

This program is supposed to check if a string is a palindrome by using only one variable and any number of stacks. It is giving me a number of error messages relating to overloaded functions, but I don't see where I overloaded it. Or did I declare the stacks wrong? I commented in the error messages after the lines of code they referred to. Thanks!

```
int main()
{
    stack <char> stackA;
    stack <char> stackB;
    stack <char> stackC;

    char avariable;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    avariable = cin.get();
    while(avariable != '\n')
    {
        if(avariable != ' ')
        {

            stackA.push(avariable);
            stackB.push(avariable);
            avariable = cin.get();
        }}

    stackC.push('$');

    while(!stackB.empty())
    {
        avariable = stackB.top; //error, cannot resolve overloaded function 'top' based on conversion to type 'char'
        stackC.push(avariable);
        stackB.pop; //statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
    }

    avariable = '$';
    stackC.push('$');

    while(!stackA.empty())
    {
        if(avariable == stackC.top) //invalid operands of type 'char' and <unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator=='
        {
            avariable = stackA.top; //cannot resolve overloaded function 'top' based on conversion to type 'char'
            stackA.pop; //cannot resolve address of overloaded function 
            stackC.pop; //cannot resolve address of overloaded function 
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The string of characters entered is not a palindrome." << endl;
        }
    }

    if (stackC.top == '$') //invalid operands of type 'char' and <unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator=='
    {
        cout <<"The string of characters entered is a palindrome." << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) template class only has member *functions* [`top()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) and [`pop()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) defined. You are trying to access them as public member objects, instead. Function calls require the use of parenthesis even if no arguments are passed.

Just replace all the occurrences of `.top` and `.pop` to `.top()` and `.pop()` respectively, and your program [should at least compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24e057a217e98d79).

Also please get used to the `std::` prefix instead of including the entire `std` namespace with `using namespace std`. It will save you potential troubles, in the long run.

Comment: Why do you say that using std:: for each instance is better? I was told the opposite by a professor, though I don't remember him explaining the benefits of it.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should have looked it up before I asked.

Comment: @Neko, don't worry. As long as you don't post a duplicate question, it's ok to ask.

Answer (score 1):

To call a function, you need parentheses:

```
stackB.top()
stackB.pop()
```

As both `top` and `pop` take no arguments, the parentheses are empty but still required.

This is no different to where you have done `stackA.empty()` or `cin.get()` for example.